# Notification between app container and app extension

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, ios-app-extension

I am developing a Today extension, and I would like to know how can I properly send a notification from an app extension to the app container, and other way around?

I am aware there are some limitations since they are different processes. So NSNotification probably does not work. I tried CFNotification, but I get some inconsistencies like double posting. Also, I was not able to send a notification to the app container when it is in background, which is a functionality I would like to use.

My final goal is to send a notification from the extension to the app container every time the extensions appears (or by tapping a button on it), so the app container will make an api resquest and update the database shared via appgroups. After updating, the app would notify the extension the data is changed.

Information about the notifications and suggestions of a better approach are welcomed.

Comment: IPC doesn't exist between an app and its extensions. The best you can get is to use something like  this https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole